# Invariant Violation Native component for "RCTCustomWebView" does not exist

Tags: react-native

Please help me to solve my problem as below :

`Invariant Violation Native component for RCTCustomWebView does not exist`

`This error is located at:`
    `in RCTCustomWebView (at WebView.android.js:296)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting Invariant Violation: Native component for "XXXXXXXXXXXX does not exist" it likely means you forgot to run react-native link or there was some error with the linking process.

Try this :

```
react-native link your-fresh-installed-module-here
```